# ActionScript3 remove child error

Tags: actionscript-3

I recently have been converting an as2 fla to as3 (new to AS3) and have the entire thing working on export, but I am getting an error when I try to remove previously loaded swf's before a new swf is loaded

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject
must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
at MethodInfo-11()
```

I know the error relates to my removeChild code here:

```
`stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeSWF);
function removeSWF (e:MouseEvent):void 
{
if(vBox.numChildren !=0){        
   // swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
    vBox.removeChild(swfLoader);// empty the movieClip memory
}
}`
```

However, I cannot seem to find a suitable rewrite for this code that will work and not have an error.  This code IS working, so I'm not sure if it would be worth my time to fix this error, or just leave it.  I've already messed with it for a couple days, so at this point it's just frustrating me that I cannot fix it.
The stage mouse click listener is useful in this case because I have a back button not shown in this code that clears the loaded swf's before moving to another scene.
Does anyone see a simple solution for this, or do you think it is unnecessary to pursue since the code does what I require?
ENTIRE CODE:

```
function launchSWF(vBox, vFile):void    {
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var swfURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(vFile);
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadProdComplete);
swfLoader.load(swfURL);

function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void {
    trace("swf file loaded");   
    vBox.removeChild(preLoader);
    vBox.addChild(swfLoader);   
    currentSWF = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);
    currentSWF.gotoAndPlay(1);
    currentSWF.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , checkLastFrame);
    swfLoader.x = 165;
    swfLoader.y = 15;

    function checkLastFrame(e:Event):void { 
        if (currentSWF.currentFrame == currentSWF.totalFrames) {
        currentSWF.stop();
        // trace("DONE");     
        }
    }      
} 
var preLoader:loader = new loader();
preLoader.x = 450;
preLoader.y = 280;
vBox.addChild(preLoader);

        function onProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent){
            var dataAmountLoaded:Number=event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal*100;
            //preLoader.bar.scaleX = dataAmountLoaded/100;
            preLoader.lpc.text= int(dataAmountLoaded)+"%";
            //trace(preLoader.bar.scaleX );
        }   
//NEW ERRORS BUT WORKING
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeSWF);
function removeSWF (e:MouseEvent):void 
{
if(vBox.numChildren !=0){        
   // swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
    vBox.removeChild(swfLoader);// empty the movieClip memory
}
}
}
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var currentSWF:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

fall_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fall_bClick);
  function fall_bClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
  var swfFile:String = 'load/fall.swf';
  launchSWF(container, swfFile);
  addChild(container);
  }

face_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, face_bClick);
  function face_bClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
  var swfFile:String = 'load/face.swf';
  launchSWF(container, swfFile);
  addChild(container);
  }

rott_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rott_bClick);
  function rott_bClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
  var swfFile:String = 'load/rottgut.swf';
  launchSWF(container, swfFile);
  addChild(container);
  }
//MORE SWFS...
```

Any advice anyone has is appreciated

Comment: You've got unclosed functions, loose code, and functions inside functions.  It would be easier/possible to follow if you clean it up and actually put the "ENTIRE CODE" in.

Comment: this is all the code, except 28 more buttons exactly like the last 3 (fall_b, face_b, rott_b) with nothing else after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `function launchSWF(vBox, vFile):void {` isn't closed. You've also got function inside functions which is easy enough for you to solve if you click the lines the curly brackets start and end on to track them.

I can't see anything wrong with the code you said has an error but I'm guessing this isn't all the code. If you using Flash Professisonal  you can use permit debugging to show the line the error is on.

**EDIT:** Please note this hasn't been tested as I'm on my mobile writing out code. That being said this should now work:

```
var container:MovieClip;
var currentSWF:MovieClip;

var swfFile:String;

var swfLoader:Loader;
var preLoader:Loader;

var swfURL:URLRequest;

init();

function init():void {
    preLoader = new Loader();
    preLoader.x = 450;
    preLoader.y = 280;
    vBox.addChild(preLoader);

    container = new MovieClip();
    currentSWF = new MovieClip();
    fall_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fall_bClick);
    face_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, face_bClick);
    rott_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rott_bClick);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeSWF);
}

function launchSWF(vBox, vFile):void {
    swfLoader = new Loader();
    swfURL = new URLRequest(vFile);
    swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
    swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadProdComplete);
    swfLoader.load(swfURL);
}

function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void {
    trace("swf file loaded");   
    vBox.removeChild(preLoader);
    vBox.addChild(swfLoader);   
    currentSWF = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);
    currentSWF.gotoAndPlay(1);

    currentSWF.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , checkLastFrame);
    swfLoader.x = 165;
    swfLoader.y = 15;
}

function checkLastFrame(e:Event):void { 
    if (currentSWF.currentFrame == currentSWF.totalFrames) {
        currentSWF.stop();
        // trace("DONE");
    }      
} 

function onProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent) {
     var dataAmountLoaded:Number = (event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100);
     //preLoader.bar.scaleX = dataAmountLoaded/100;
     preLoader.lpc.text = int(dataAmountLoaded)+"%";
     //trace(preLoader.bar.scaleX );
}

function removeSWF (e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(vBox.numChildren !=0){        
        //swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
        vBox.removeChild(swfLoader);// empty the movieClip memory
    }
}

function fall_bClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    swfFile = 'load/fall.swf';
    launchSWF(container, swfFile);
    addChild(container);
}

function face_bClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    swfFile = 'load/face.swf';
    launchSWF(container, swfFile);
    addChild(container);
}

function rott_bClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    swfFile = 'load/rottgut.swf';
    launchSWF(container, swfFile);
    addChild(container);
}
```

Comment: it is closed here towards the end of the code 
         `}var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();`  I am new tho as3, so I will remove all the functions inside functions and see what happens

Comment: when I take the functions out of the other functions, I too many errors to count, mostly about undefined properties.

Comment: The undefined property errors are caused by trying to access something that doesn't exist in the current scope. If you post up your project or at least the class you're working on I'll take a look.

Comment: I'm getting a vBox undefined error, and when I try to fix that, i get the removeChild error again

Comment: I've had a look into your code and found a few things that need fixing. First of all there is a lot of repetitive code, although this isn't causing you errors it will in the long run make things easier to understand and read. I've fixed this by using one function for all your MouseEvent clicks with a switch statement.

Comment: You do still have 2 errors which I cannot fix as I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. The first issue is that vBox doesn't exist - what is vBox supposed to be? The second issue is that you're trying to access .text on your preLoader Loader variable. You cannot access the .text property on the Loader class. I've amended the project and uploaded it here: http://www.anthonybirch.org/stackoverflow/main.fla

Comment: Since we have worked out the problem with your original question being that vBox doesn't exist can you please mark the answer above as correct and message me with anymore problems.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at this.  I was beginning to realize that the whole function inside function thing was the reason I was getting the error, so I was in the process of trying to rewrite this a different way.  I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have this rewritten.  I could not get the vBox errors cleared in the original code, and I was getting many other errors with what was posted.  The vBox code was seen on a tutorial. I think it was supposed to reference the loader for the preloader and the swf, and vFile was for the actual .swf.  The following code preloads multiple swfs and clears them with no errors.  I appreciate your help AntBirch.  I'm beginning to understand loaders in as3 a little more now.

```
//LOAD FIRST PIECE ON OPEN (required to removeChild later)
   var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
   var defaultSWF:URLRequest = new URLRequest("load/fall.swf");
   swfLoader.load(defaultSWF);
   swfLoader.x = 165;
   swfLoader.y = 15;
   addChild(swfLoader);
//PRELOADER
   var preLoader:loader = new loader();
   preLoader.x = 450;
   preLoader.y = 280;

function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void {
   trace("swf file loaded");    
   removeChild(preLoader);
   addChild(swfLoader); 
}

function onProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent){
   var dataAmountLoaded:Number=event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal*100;
   preLoader.lpc.text= int(dataAmountLoaded)+"%";
}
//BUTTONS
function btnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

   swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
   removeChild(swfLoader);
   swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,      onProgressHandler);
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  loadProdComplete);    
addChild(preLoader);    
var newSWFRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("load/" + event.target.name +    ".swf");
swfLoader.load(newSWFRequest);
swfLoader.x = 165;
swfLoader.y = 15;;
addChild(swfLoader);
}

// BUTTON LISTENERS
fall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);  
face.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
rott.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);  
angel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
ratts.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick); 
metal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
//etc...    


//BACK BUTTON
BB3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BB3Click);

function BB3Click(e:MouseEvent):void {
   swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
   removeChild(swfLoader);
   this.gotoAndPlay(1 ,"Scene 2")
}
```